# Both clickTAG and clickTag in the same Flash file

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, dfa, clicktag

Instead of having two separate files, can you put both DFA (clickTag) and DFP (clickTAG) code in the same flash file? Or will the code conflict with each other? For example (AS2):

```
///DFP///

RedBtn.onRelease = function() {
getURL(clickTAG,"_blank");
}

///DFA///

RedBtn.onRelease = function() {
getURL(clickTag,"_blank");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since variable names are case sensitive, there shouldn't be any problem having `clickTag` and `clickTAG` as separate variables with their own definitions.

You would want to combine the two sample functions however, as the second will overwrite the first; `RedBtn` can only have one definition for `onRelease` at any given time.

If you replace your code with the following, both URLs can be visited successfully.

```
RedBtn.onRelease = function() {

    ///DFP///
    getURL(clickTAG,"_blank");

    ///DFA///
    getURL(clickTag,"_blank");

}
```